# Cannot access Facebook from my PC

Tags: google-chrome, internet

I can access all of the sites on my computer except facebook. It gives the connection timed out error. I tried unchecking `dns prefetech`, `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /renew`, `flush dns` and clearing the cookies and cache. None of this is helping. What could be the fix? FYI its not accessible on any of the browsers

Comment: Not programming related; voted to move to superuser.com.

Answer (score 5):

Is this at your place of work or behind someone elses router/firewall?
If so then they may have blocked Facebook
Often work machines are blocked by management to stop users using it.